# Flutter Image_Picker plugin error while running pub get

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting this error in Android Studio iOS simulator when trying to run pub get after adding flutter image_picker plugin.

```
Because image_picker >=0.7.0 depends on image_picker_platform_interface ^2.0.0 which depends on http ^0.13.0, image_picker >=0.7.0 requires http ^0.13.0.
And because http >=0.13.0 depends on http_parser ^4.0.0, image_picker >=0.7.0 requires http_parser ^4.0.0.
And because dio 3.0.10 depends on http_parser >=0.0.1 <4.0.0 and no versions of dio match >3.0.10 <4.0.0, image_picker >=0.7.0 is incompatible with dio ^3.0.10.
So, because brief9_pro depends on both dio ^3.0.10 and image_picker ^0.7.5+3, version solving failed.



pub get failed (1; So, because brief9_pro depends on both dio ^3.0.10 and image_picker ^0.7.5+3, version solving failed.)
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try adding this line to your pubspec.yaml

```
dependency_overrides:
   http_parser: ^4.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your dio and http_parser to latest version

```
dependency_overrides:
      dio: ^4.0.0
       http_parser: ^4.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by:

- `flutter upgrade`
- `updating dio plugin`
- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 0):

Its because of some other package you already installed is not supporting this version. So solution is remove package version from **pubspec.yaml** file (all error getting packages )and run `flutter pub get` .

Example :-
replace this

```
dependency_overrides:
   http_parser: ^4.0.0
```

with this

```
dependency_overrides:
   http_parser:
```